# In mysql is there a way to query for a string in the db but only do an alphanumeric comparison (ignore special chars)

Tags: mysql, sql, alphanumeric

I'm trying to figure out whether it is possible to query a mysql table for a string but have it ignore special characters in the field that is querying in the db....

A better way of clarifying what I'm trying to achieve could be with an example.

If I had a table named "Games" which had 2 columns being "id" and "title" which contained these rows:

```
id    title
-----------------------
1     f-zero
2     quake
3     quake 4
```

And I wanted to be able to search for "fzero" (notice the search string is without the hyphen), i.e.

```
SELECT g.* FROM Games as g WHERE alphanumeric(title) = "fzero";
```

Would this be possible in one way or another?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you have some structure in the title attribute values, you can use a regexp condition, like:

```
SELECT g.* FROM Games as g WHERE title REGEXP 'f[0-9\-!\\]*z[0-9\-!\\]*e[0-9\-!\\]*r[0-9\-!\\]*o[0-9\-!\\]*';
```